# Using variables from another module wih a while loop

Tags: python

main.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('Pygame Projects')
import sub
from sub import *

loop = True

while loop:
    print_hello()
    true_the_another_loop()

while anotherLoop:
    print_world()
```

sub.py:

```
def true_the_another_loop():
    loop = False
    anotherLoop = True

def print_hello():
    print "hello"

def print_world():
    print "world"
```

When I run main.py, it prints only `"hello"`. Why is `"world"` not being printed?

In `true_the_another_loop()`, the line `loop = Flase` does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the new values of those variables. Because they were just local variables, they are limited to only that function. You need to pass their values to the other variables.

```
...
while loop:
    print_hello()
    loop, anotherLoop = true_the_another_loop()
...
def true_the_another_loop():
    loop = False
    anotherLoop = True
    return [loop,anotherLop]
```

Comment: you don't need to put the return values in a list